# How to enable _all_ warnings with -fpermissive from g++?

Tags: c++, g++

There seem to be cases where the -fpermissive option results in errors being ignored altogether, rather than "downgraded" to warnings, as widely available documentation suggests.

The -Wall option is clearly not enough.  What other options are needed in order to have all such downgraded warnings reported by g++?

An example came up with the Nodejs C++ addon library.

```
In file included from /opt/nodejs/linux64/8.9.4/include/node/node.h:63:0,
                 from /opt/nan/linux64/2.9.2/include/nan.h:51,
                 from /build/ndjs/include/blob.h:59,
                 from /build/ndjs/src/blob.cpp:2:
/opt/nodejs/linux64/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h: In instantiation of ‘v8::Local<T>::Local(v8::Local<S>) [with S = v8::Integer; T = v8::Int32]’:
/build/src/ndjs/blob.cpp:507:1:   required from here
/opt/nodejs/linux64/8.9.4/include/node/v8.h:207:5: error: invalid conversion from ‘v8::Integer*’ to ‘v8::Int32*’ [-fpermissive]
     TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
     ^
```

Recompiling with -fpermissive (and -Wall, of course) results in a clean compile: no warnings at all.  What happened? (i.e. Why?)

The TYPE_CHECK() macro tests for type compatibility in pointer assignments:

```
#define TYPE_CHECK(T, S)                                       \
  while (false) {                                              \
    *(static_cast<T* volatile*>(0)) = static_cast<S*>(0);      \
  }
```

It fails for downcasts (v8::Int32 is derived from v8::Integer), but somehow succeeds without warnings when -fpermissive is in effect.  Shouldn't there be a warning about the static downcast?

Comment: `-fpermissive` is supposed to be used for compiler development / testing purposes, you should never use it to compile regular code and / or expect to get any particular results from doing so.

Comment: `-fpermissive` happened. If you have to tell the compiler to devieate from the standard then you probably need to rethink what your doing in the first place. -Wall is your default.

Comment: Instead of trashing -fpermissive, which I can do as well as anyone, please try to address the question: how are downgraded warnings enabled? This comes often when dealing with third party code.